# How can I copy the location of multiple bones of a skeleton and paste them to another skeleton?

Tags: scripting

[image]

In edit mode, I want to change all the bone's location on the right skeleton to match with the left skeleton.

Comment: Why not just use the left skeleton, or a duplicate of it, instead?

Comment: The right skeleton contains animation

Comment: You can assign the action to the right skeleton.  It may not do what you want, because bone axes and rest position are different; but if you change left skeleton to right skeleton, that will also be the case.

Answer (score -1):

I think what you're looking for is called animation retargeting. and there are a few addons that do this inside of blender.

1. Rokoko (free)

   - https://support.rokoko.com/hc/en-us/articles/4410463492241-Install-the-Blender-plugin
   - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6kj_ZX_lIL4
2. Auto-rig pro

   - https://blendermarket.com/products/auto-rig-pro
   - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HHnt-3uLSUo

Comment: Hello, Dulsara, welcome to BSE .. we do like answers to be self-contained, for the archive. Is there any way you could demo the use of Rokoko on a toy example? If that's too much, or you don't have enough information, this post would be better as a comment, and will be converted to one.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the information. I think a comment would suffice. Edit - Just realized I cannot make comments though...